# Accessing JSON values with a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to access JSON data with jQuery and grab a specific set of values based on a variable.  I've done this before using [] but for some reason I can't figure out what is going wrong this time.

My JSON file (being read in by getJSON, and named jsonmaker.php) looks like this:

```
{"0107001":{"label":"Canada","x":"0","y":"0.34"},"0107002":{"label":"USA","x":"-0.16","y":"0.53"}}
```

I then have a function which is essentially this:

```
function addAttrib(attrib) {
$.getJSON("jsonmaker.php", function(data) {
    alert(data[attrib].label);
}
}
```

But it keeps returning undefined.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?  I've checked to make sure the var going to attrib is 0107001, no problems there.

Also, I know my JSON file is a php file so I could filter what's returned to match the attrib value, but I'm looking to develop something that can run purely on HTML and JS, so I could just pack the JSON file for the project and take it with me.  No need for a web server w/ PHP etc.

Comment: When you look at the "data" variable in Firebug or the IE debugger, what **does** it contain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data access itself works for me:

```
var data = {"0107001":{"label":"Canada","x":"0","y":"0.34"},"0107002":{"label":"USA","x":"-0.16","y":"0.53"}};
var attrib = "0107002";
alert(data[attrib].label); // USA
```

Make sure that `attrib` remains untouched between the moment you call addAttrib() and the moment when the AJAX request completes and your anonymous callback function gets called.

**Update:** is this your real code? You have at least one syntax error:

```
function addAttrib(attrib) {
    $.getJSON("jsonmaker.php", function(data) {
        alert(data[attrib].label);
    }); // <- Please note missing ");"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, `$.getJSON()` doesn't always return an object. Depending on the MIME type that the server returns along with the JSON, you might end up with a string instead of an object. Check what `data` contains. If it's a string, you must manually parse it using `eval()` (old style) or `JSON.parse()` (new browsers only).

Comment: Also, if the object isn't too complex, try converting it to a string and use alert or prompt to display it so you can see exactly what it is.  I usually use JSON.stringify to do that (http://www.json.org/js.html).

Answer (score 0):

try to list all properties from data, to have sure the data is being returned:

```
for (var p in data){
  if (data.hasOwnProperty(p){
    alert(data[p]);
  }
}
```

It's not your solution but with this you can know how your data is coming.