# Use a variable to access json object?

Tags: jquery, json

I'd like to use a variable to help me dig into a json object. I know I want to use "r1m1" in this case but I won't necessarily know where that key will appear in the json structure.

json structure...

```
{
"matchups": {
        "r1m1": {
                "category": "Cat 1",
                "team1": "Team 1",
                "team2": "Team 2"
               },
        "r1m2": {
               "category": "Cat 2",
                "team1": "Team 1",
                "team2": "Team 2"
            }
    }
}
```

Here I am trying unsuccessfully to use "currentpage" to get at the "r1m1" team name.

```
var currentPage = "r1m1";

$.getJSON("json.js", function(data) {
    var thisvalue = data.matchups. + currentPage + .team1;
    alert(thisvalue);
}
```

Comment: what makes you think you need those plus signs? i think you can just get it with data.matchups.r1m1.team1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing JSON values with a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043529/accessing-json-values-with-a-variable)

Comment: `data.matchups[currentPage].team1`, Bracket notation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of dot notation for the variable, you can use bracket notation

```
data.matchups[currentPage].team1
```